# sum values of the same month in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm trying the sum of values of the same month but the result is rows with the date and the values separated.

My code is

```
 select 
    case extract(month from date(m.data)) 
    when extract(month from current_date) then 'Current Month' 
    else to_char(m.data, 'TMMonth/YYYY') end as "Date", 
    sum(m.valor) as "Result" 
    from movimentacao m 
    group by m.data 
    order by m.data;
```

and my result is

```
Apr/2015      | 150.75
Apr/2015      | 15.00
Current Month | 10.00
Current Month | 2.34
```

what I need is to group this values by month to sum works, but when I try to group by month the sql get error because I'm using the m.data in function and I need to group by from m.data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not `GROUP BY m.data` (presumably a `date`), but by the month you extracted from it. You will then run into a problem with grouping and the only way to circumvent that is to do the grouping in a sub-query by year and month and in the main query you then re-create a `date` from the year and month and then you can output exactly what you were asking for:

```
SELECT
  CASE
  WHEN extract(year FROM current_date) = yr
   AND extract(month FROM current_date) = mon THEN 'Current month'
  ELSE to_char((yr || '-' || mon || '-01')::date, 'TMMon/YYYY')
  END AS "Date",
  "Result"
FROM (
  SELECT extract(year FROM m.data) AS yr,
         extract(month FROM m.data) AS mon,
         sum(m.valor) AS "Result"
  FROM movimentacao m
  GROUP BY yr, mon) AS sum_by_yr_mon
ORDER by yr, mon;
```

This query will sort in chronological order, even over multiple years, and "Current month" comes last.

Comment: Thats give ERROR:  column "m.data" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: My bad. You need a sub-query on numerical date values for year and month to get a proper chronological sort and then in the main query you do the formatting to the TMMon/YYYY format. Note that `GROUP BY` is done in the sub-query where the sum of `valor` is calculated, and `ORDER BY` in the main query but using the numerical year and month values from the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
select 
   CASE WHEN 
        to_char(event_date, 'MM/YYYY')= to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'MM/YYYY')THEN 'Current Month'
        ELSE to_char(event_date, 'MM/YYYY')
   END as month_year,
sum(m.valor) as "Result" 
from movimentacao m 
group by 1 
order by 1;
```

Tried with Postgres, [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c1cb6/1)

Comment: This will sort "Current Month" before all other months except "Apr/xxxx" and "Aug/xxxx" and months will in general be out of chronological order.

Comment: @Patrick it sort moths correctly 01/2015 then 02/2015 etc. and put the "Current Month at the last row because 'c' is after numeric character

Comment: @DanielMenegasso Happy for that, please select answer as accepted

Comment: Sorting is not chronological if you use the `TMMonth/YYYY` format that the OP asked for.

Comment: If the year is 2014 then becomes not chronological